# Got "Type may not be empty" error when trying to add "Discount details" in a sales order through Web API

Tags: acumatica

I tried to add sales order with a pre-set discount code through web API using code as follows:

```
        SO301000Content SO301000 = context.SO301000GetSchema();
        context.SO301000Clear();

        List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();


        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "SO", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderType });
        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "<NEW>", LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr });
        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.OrderCustomerInfo.AcctCD, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Customer });
        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.OrderLocationInfo.ID, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.Location });

        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.ShippingTotal.ToString(), LinkedCommand = SO301000.Totals.PremiumFreight });

        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "N30", LinkedCommand = SO301000.FinancialSettingsFinancialInformation.Terms});


        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.OrderNumber, LinkedCommand = SO301000.OrderSummary.ExternalReference });

        if (orderInfo.ShippingTotal > 0) { 
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.ShippingTotal.ToString(), LinkedCommand = SO301000.Totals.PremiumFreight });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.ShippingTaxCategory, LinkedCommand = SO301000.Totals.FreightTaxCategory });
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderInfo.PromoCode))
        {
            cmds.Add(SO301000.DiscountDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow);
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.PromoCode, LinkedCommand = SO301000.DiscountDetails.DiscountCode });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "000", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DiscountDetails.SequenceID });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "Group", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DiscountDetails.Type });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.OrderQty.ToString(), LinkedCommand = SO301000.DiscountDetails.DiscountableQty });
        }



        //add line items
        foreach (OrderItem item in orderInfo.OrderItems)
        {
            cmds.Add(SO301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow);
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = item.InventoryCD, LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = item.Quantity.ToString(), LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Quantity });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "Server", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Warehouse });


            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "True", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.ManualDiscount});

            if (item.DiscountPercent > 0)
            {
                cmds.Add(new Value { Value = item.DiscountPercent.ToString(), LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.DiscountPercent, Commit = true });
            }
            else if (item.DiscountAmount > 0)
            {
                cmds.Add(new Value { Value = item.DiscountAmount.ToString(), LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.DiscountAmount, Commit = true });
            }

        }

        cmds.Add(SO301000.Actions.Save);
        cmds.Add(SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderNbr);
        cmds.Add(SO301000.OrderSummary.OrderTotal);
        cmds.Add(SO301000.OrderSummary.TaxTotal);
        cmds.Add(SO301000.OrderSummary.Location);
        cmds.Add(SO301000.OrderSummary.Customer);

        SO301000Content[] SO30100content = context.SO301000Submit(cmds.ToArray());
```

however, I got error as follows:

PX.Data.PXException: Error #12: Inserting  'Sales Order Discount Detail' record raised one or more errors. Please review. Error: 'Type' may not be empty. ---> PX.Data.PXOuterException: Error #12: Inserting  'Sales Order Discount Detail' record raised one or more errors. Please review.

You can see in my code I assigned "Group" to the "SO301000.DiscountDetails.Type" explicitly, which is exactly as same as that discount code was set up - I don't understand why I'm still getting error...

Thanks.

Comment: try adding a commit = true after you set the value of type. Also try to replicate the same scenario in UI.

Comment: @Hybridzz, "commit=true" didn't work. The same process did work in UI though.

Comment: Anybody can help? I tried all different ways to do it but none of them worked. @Gabriel, could you please take a few minutes looking at my question and lend me a hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I figured it out - it turned out "adding discount details" code should be placed AFTER code for adding line items, i.e. my code should be changed to something like:

```
   ..........

   //add line items
    foreach (OrderItem item in orderInfo.OrderItems)
    {
        cmds.Add(SO301000.DocumentDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow);
        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = item.InventoryCD, LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.InventoryID });
        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = item.Quantity.ToString(), LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Quantity });
        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "Server", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.Warehouse });


        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "True", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.ManualDiscount});

        if (item.DiscountPercent > 0)
        {
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = item.DiscountPercent.ToString(), LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.DiscountPercent, Commit = true });
        }
        else if (item.DiscountAmount > 0)
        {
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = item.DiscountAmount.ToString(), LinkedCommand = SO301000.DocumentDetails.DiscountAmount, Commit = true });
        }

    }


    .........

  //add discount details if there is promo code being used in sales order
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(orderInfo.PromoCode))
    {
        cmds.Add(SO301000.DiscountDetails.ServiceCommands.NewRow);
        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.PromoCode, LinkedCommand = SO301000.DiscountDetails.DiscountCode });
        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "000", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DiscountDetails.SequenceID });
        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "Group", LinkedCommand = SO301000.DiscountDetails.Type });
        cmds.Add(new Value { Value = orderInfo.OrderQty.ToString(), LinkedCommand = SO301000.DiscountDetails.DiscountableQty });
    }

    cmds.Add(SO301000.Actions.Save);

   ........
```